# Javascript url redirection when there is a hash in url path

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect my urls from this location :

```
  http://example.com/#!foo
```

to this location

```
http://example.com/folder/#!foo
```

The redirection is working if I remove the **if** condition, but I want to redirect my urls
Only when there is a # in url path.

I have been trying the following code for the last 30minutes without any success.

```
<script>
if(window.location.hash)

 {
 window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash)
 }
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've proved works perfectly fine, what browser are you testing in? Make sure to test it in a new window as well. Either way there are alternative options answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if( window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1)

 {
 window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do.

```js
var address = window.location.href
if (adderss.indexOf('#') > -1){ window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash) }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
   var url = window.location.href + "";
   var str="";
   if(url.lastIndexOf("#") != -1)
   str = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("#"),url.length);
   window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/folder/"+str;
```

Hope it helps, cheers :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` to check if there is a specific char (or string) in a string.

```
<script>
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
        window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try with the following event,

```
window.onhashchange = function(e){ 
  window.location = window.location.pathname+'/foo/'+window.location.hash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why do not you try IndexOf

```
if((window.location.pathname).indexOf('#') > 0)

 {
     window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash)
 }
```